# What is the correct way to grant permissions needed for Visual Studio 2012/2013 to connect to SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, permissions, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm attempting to use the "Empty Project" template in Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2013 and I'm having trouble determining the least-privilege way to do so.

When attempting to add an event receiver to my project, I get the following error:

[image: Cannot connect to the SharePoint site]

I have access to the site and can open it on the same machine so it is not the hosts file issue that you'll find when searching on the error.  It is also not the Loopback Check issue you'll find when searching.  The developer account is a local administrator (required since Visual Studio must run as administrator)

Many of the "fixes" I've found are similar to [this](http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/03/19/resolving-vs-2010-solution-deployment-issues-for-sharepoint-2010-projects/) and recommend granting the developer db_owner or sys_admin rights on the databases.

Since we want to do everything possible to keep developers *out* of the SharePoint Databases, I can't believe this is the accepted best practice, even in DEV.

I did find that granting SharePoint_Shell_Access rights (via [Add-SPShellAdmin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607596%28v=office.15%29.aspx)) to both the config and content databases, the developers appear to have the required permissions.  That makes more sense to me... even though at the end of the day the developers are ending up with near db_owner rights, we don't have to open SQL Management Studio to do it.

What's everyone else doing?

Comment: Just to be sure, every dev has their own server they're remoting to, right? And, since each dev has their own server, why does it matter if they have dbowner access?

Comment: It depends - in this specific instance, this is a shared environment so multiple developers have access to it.  Ideally I'd like to find a way that doesn't give developers access to the databases via SQL tools.  The Add-SPShellAdmin method above does still give them access via SQL tools :(

Comment: Every time a dev deploys a farm solution, it recycles the app pool. It is extremely frustrating to deal with this in a multi-user environment, and so it is absolutely standard for each dev to have access to their own server to do development.

Comment: Understood, Mike2500.  However, that's not what I'm talking about here :)  This isn't their only development environment - it is a sandbox.  Most hard-core development will be done on developer's own machines like you're suggesting.

Comment: Then I guess I don't know the purpose. If it's a QA box, then VS doesn't belong at all. If it's actually a dev box, then let them have full access. But it's neither of those? It's a dev box where only "light" VS dev is done, because... ?

Comment: Mike, I know what you're getting at but you're missing the focus of my question.  I'm not looking for guidance on how to architect or use a development environment.

How do we allow developers to use the tools MS has given us WITHOUT granting more permission than is needed.  Going around handing out db_owner access is not acceptable in many environments - especially when it doesn't seem like it should be required.  We absolutely don't want to allow/encourage folks to use SQL tools to gain access to the SharePoint databases - so why give them that level of permissions?

Comment: Oh, I get it. I just see a lot of sharepoint questions where the answer is to step back and see if something should really be done. Didn't mean to be a bother. In my experience, Devs have full access to their server: local admin, sharepoint admin, and dba. Also, in my experience, shared dev environments for SP are a disaster. But, how to have a dev env where the devs aren't DBAs? I'll have to let others answer that.

Comment: @RaymondMitchell-iwkid actually I will agree with Mike on this one.. In our environment, we also have multiple stages before the solution goes into Production.. But we only have full access rights (dba, sharepoint, local machine) on our own personal machines, we do all development on.. Once we complete, for QA we put a request to Operations team.. Who deploys the solution and activate necessary features for us on QA environment.. You might need to think over the structure/management of servers.. an extra layer of Operations team might help in this case..

Comment: @RaymondMitchell-iwkid I am facing the same problem right now. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I did not find a great solution - ended up granting db_owner rights on the local dev boxes.  I still think it is a crap solution but to be honest we should be developing fewer and fewer SharePoint solutions like this anyway so I suppose it'll take care of itself in a few years.